# Where to find the NLU Context Tag for Nuance Speech kit configuration Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, speech-recognition

I am using Nuance Speech kit in Swift 3 , I had downloaded the sample app for swift  , the configuration has a variable ,

// Only needed if using NLU/Bolt
var SKSNLUContextTag = "!NLU_CONTEXT_TAG!"
I am able to find all the other credentials required for speech recognition except the context tag .
How / where to find SKSNLUContextTag value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to sign up for Nuance Mix. After that you'll get NLU context tags.

```
https://developer.nuance.com/mix
```

Comment: Please specify the way, by which we can get actually!